# NFS server on Kubernetes minikube reports `exportfs: / does not support NFS export`

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, minikube

```
kubectl logs nfs-685944f556-r2pjr                     
Serving /exports
Serving /
rpcinfo: can't contact rpcbind: : RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
Starting rpcbind
exportfs: / does not support NFS export
NFS started
```

nfs.deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs
  labels:
    app: nfs
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
          - name: nfs
            containerPort: 2049
          - name: mountd
            containerPort: 20048
          - name: rpcbind
            containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /exports
            name: mypvc
      volumes:
        - name: mypvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-data
```

What does exportfs refer to? How can I diagnose this further?

Within the nfs pod, not too sure why it's exporting `/`?

```
[root@nfs-685944f556-r2pjr /]# cat /etc/exports
/exports *(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_root_squash)
/ *(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_root_squash)
```

Answer (score 2):

> not too sure why it's exporting /

It is done by [run_nfs.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/nfs-data/run_nfs.sh) script, running with two arguments:

```
/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/run_nfs.sh /exports /
```

There's an issue with the image [gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL/volume-nfs?gcrImageListsize=30), so it is  suggested to use [jsafrane/nfs-data](https://hub.docker.com/r/jsafrane/nfs-data/) image instead

See the corresponding github [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24687)